# poorly accommodated in a row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this form group in Bootstrap 4 [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/4275/):

```
<div class="m-portlet__body">
  <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">
                Correo electrónico
              </label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
    </div>
    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">
                Nombre
              </label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
    </div>
    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">
                Apellido
              </label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
    </div>
    <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">
                Perfil
              </label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want something like this:
[image]

but for some reason it dont responsive at my row group as you can see in fiddle:
[image]

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong with it? Regards

Comment: I see that you added col-lg-2 class to label wrap. You should have label and input in the same div wrap with col-lg-3 class.

Comment: so label need to be inside div without class and I shoud get desire results? @JakubMuda

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/4281/ Updated, You have to add all other resolutions with the Form-group Class Div box for the both label and input box,

Comment: col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 all of them,

Comment: I saw it, but why it don´t have 100% of width? @QasimRamzan

Comment: you have to do it by yourself, :) please take look the bootstrap documentations here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job. You need to place label in the same div as input.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="m-portlet__body">
  <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>Correo electrónico</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>Apellido</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>Perfil</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: you need to run the snippet in full screen to see the result. On smaller screen obviously you have everything in one column. It looks exactly as on your photo and this should be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="m-portlet__body">
        <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label class="col-form-label">
                    Correo electrónico
                </label>

                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label class="col-form-label">
                    Nombre
                </label>

                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label class="col-form-label">
                    Apellido
                </label>

                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <label class="col-form-label">
                    Perfil
                </label>

                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control m-input" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel" placeholder="Enter full name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```